# Dynamically Notify the View from the View-Model in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

In my WPF application, I have to create an object designer. This designer is a ListView of many other user-controls (custom-Grid wich contains costum-stackpanel wich contains... which contains my custom-objects to show).

So, to better structure my designer, I create a template for each hierarchical level, and put it in a View (as a user-control). In parallel, I created for each of these views, thier correspanding viewModels.

to bind the views to thier view-models, I put in the file App.xaml the following code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:DesignerViewModel}">
        <View:Designer />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:FirstLevelViewModel}">
        <View:FirstLevel />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SecondLevelViewModel}">
        <View:Secondlevel />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ThirdLevelViewModel}">
        <View:Thirdlevel />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:CircleViewModel}">
        <View:Circle />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:RectangleViewModel}">
        <View:Rectangle />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

It works when I load the application in the first time (I think because  the binding is done only in when the constructors of the views are in creation). But after that, every modification in the View-Models is not automatically notified to the views !!!

The only solution I found, is to re-create my designer-view after any view-Model modification !!

Does anyone have a better solution ?? because I think that my solution is not really clean !!

**NB: I Implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in all my viewModels.**

UPDATE>>>>

So, I'll give an example :

Here is  my Designer Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Single"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding FirstLevelViewModelList}" >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <View:FirstLevel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Here is my DesignerViewModel Class:

```
 public class DesignerViewModel : AViewModel
{
    #region Property

    public int FirstLevelCounter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<FirstLevelViewModel> FirstLevelViewModelList;

    public List<FirstLevelViewModel> FirstLevelViewModelList
    {
        get { return FirstLevelViewModelList; }
        set { FirstLevelViewModelList = value; 
OnPropertyChanged("FirstLevelViewModelList"); }
    }

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    private DesignerViewModel()
    {
        FirstLevelViewModelList = new List<FirstLevelViewModel>();
        FirstLevelCounter = 0;

    }

    private static DesignerViewModel instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static DesignerStringViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new DesignerViewModel();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

And here is my FirstLevel Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Single"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondLevelViewModelList}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Height="auto">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Finally, here is my FirstLevelViewModel Class:

public class FirstLevelViewModel : AViewModel
    {
        #region Property

```
    private List<SecondLevelViewModel> SecondLevelViewModelList;
    public List<SecondLevelViewModel> SecondLevelViewModelList
    {
        get { return SecondLevelViewModelList; }
        set { SecondLevelViewModelList = value; 
OnPropertyChanged("SecondLevelViewModelList"); }
    }


    #region Constructor


    public FirstLevelViewModel()
    {
        SecondLevelViewModelList = new List<SecondLevelViewModel>();

    }

    #endregion 

}
```

END-UPDATE>>>>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal lists don't implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) which is necessary, similar to INotifyPropertyChanged to tell WPF and the binding engine that something has changed so the view can update.

You have two options:

1. Use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of List
2. Create your own collection type and implement INotifyCollectionChanged

Answer (score 0):

Your view model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when a property of it is changed.

Comment: I did it of course !! but I think that the problem is putting the binding in App.Xaml ! so after finishing the creation... the binding is lost !

Comment: @Alvaro: No, that's not what is happening. Maybe you need to provide a little more info about your code.